# WCF and ef 4.0 performance is very bad .... Site works very slow 

Tags: wcf, performance, linq, entity-framework

we have a project in which we have used WCF because we have multiple sites which pull up the same data .... We have used HTTPBinding in WCF and EF 4.0 to interact with the database .. When it was moved to production environment we found that the site was very slow .... Do you know any way how we could increase the performance drastically ... EF is causing a lot performance issues ... Please suggest next steps

**Service Contract**

```
[ServiceContract] 
public interface ICommonService 
{ 
     [OperationContract] 
     LoginDTO AuthenticateUser(string userName, string password, int ownerId); 
}

 <service name="MyService.Services.CommonService">
        <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          name="CommonServiceEndpoint" contract="MyService.Services.Contracts.ICommonService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/MyService.Services/ICommonService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
```

We have introduced indexing but it doesn't increase performance so much

```
 using (MyService.DataAccess.MyService_RedesignEntities context = new MyService_RedesignEntities())
                {
            context.ContextOptions.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
                    context.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
                    ObjectParameter StrOutput = new ObjectParameter("chvnOutputMesage", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                    objResult = context.spAuthenticateUser(ownerId, userName, encryptedPassword).FirstOrDefault();     
            return objResult;
        }
```

Comment: (1) Service Contract, (2) WCF configuration, (3) table description (columns, datatypes, indexes), (4) EF statement you're using to fetch the data

Comment: we are taking care of indexing right now ... but our tech architect thinks its a problem with the hardware .. we have not used InstanceContext Mode ... i think by default it is per session ... we have hosted our site on IIS 7.5 and all the sites are hosted on the same  server .... How do we decide if its a hardware configuration or code limitation or how should the code be optimized

Comment: **Please don't put large snippets of code into comments!!!** really hard to read. Instead: **update** your question by editing it!!

Comment: we have used DTO's to transfer data ... but we haven't used the DataMember attribute.... Do u have any idea how i can check which query is taking time to run and if i have to do something in the WCF configuration ... I'm new to WCF and we are in a big problem .. i cant explain it..... Please suggest some tools how to optimize my linq queries and increase the performance of the site ... We have also considered options like load balncing on the server

Comment: Your question doesn't show much effort in determining (i.e. measuring) where the problem really is. How do you know that EF is the bottleneck?

Comment: coz it takes a lot of time to execute quires the first time and the rest of the queries take time but not as much of the as the first one ... and if the data is to huge it takes time to execute and wen the data is returned i get a error msg stating that the underlying connection has closed

Comment: use SQL profiler to look at the queries that are being sent - maybe you have an N + 1 problem through lazy loading

Comment: We have set Lazy Loading property to false ... is there anything else that needs to be done

Comment: a load balancer should really be one of the last things you consider, especially when you haven't really profiled the application to see what queries it's running and where you actually have a bottleneck.

Comment: how do i check the bottleneck of my code ... I'm really new to all of this stuff .. Could you provide some more details

Comment: First of all comments are not for discussion. If you are not able to describe your problem in the question people will not help you anyway. Also providing information like "very slow" means nothing. Provide information about what is slow, how did you measure it, what do you see in network tracing and SQL profiling (including times) and what does your code really do because at the moment you have just flushed some code snippet showing probably call to stored procedure - so EF really doesn't have to much to do with your code.

Comment: We have three sites and we access the data from WCF serivce which works on BasicHTTP binding  ... I recorded the time using a stopwatch and it was slow we changed the linq to sp it increased the performance but at this point of time we cant change all linq to sp bcoz the site is in production and i cant really share any code or data is because my company wont allow me to do so... I need a way to find how my linq can be optimized ... and if there is a tool which can tell me which linq takes more time for execution